# Show events in fullcalendar.js shift-wise (Morning, day, evening, night) for basicDay view and basicWeek view

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, fullcalendar

I have many events for each day. Is there a way to separate these events in horizontal shift-wise categories? Can I add an extra flag (or class viz: morning, day, evening, night) along with     'title:' and     'start:' so that the events would organize in respective horizontal shifts within a same day? I used

```
start: new Date(y,m,d,h,i),
allDay:false
```

to show different events of the same day.

I could then limit just 5 events on each shifts using eventLimit. p.s. I am only using basicDay and basicWeek view.

Answer (score 1):

You can add 'className' parameter in youe event object. And different class with color by checking event time.

Like

```
var eventClass = '';

if (event.start > night && event.start < day) {
  var eventClass = 'morningClass';
} else if (event.start > morning &&  event.start <  evening) {
  var eventClass = 'dayClass';
} else if (event.start > day &&  event.start <  night) {
  var eventClass = 'eveningClass';
} else if (event.start > evening &&  event.start <  morning) {
  var eventClass = 'nightClass';
}
```

then

```
start: new Date(y,m,d,h,i),
allDay:false,
className: eventClass
```

and based on className count (using [clientEvents (method)](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) )you can restrict 5 event's per shift.

Comment: I no longer have access to the code file so cannot try your answer. Thanks for the help though, might be helpful for someone who comes looking for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your requirement, you need to use resource view feature of the calendar.
Here is a [post](http://embed.plnkr.co/cX9dH8eTjKaddJ0Gpw21) about the resource view

Comment: I no longer have access to the code file so cannot try your answer. Thanks for the help though, might be helpful for someone who comes looking for this issue.